# System.Net.Http not found after migrating from .netcore 2.1 to asp.net 4.7.2

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll, .net-core, nuget-package

I recently migrated my project from .netcore 2.1 to asp.net 4.7.2, because of some 3rd party .dll. The solution builds and runs locally. It also builds on our dev environment in TeamCity. However, it does not work in Azure. On checking the logs I get the following error:

> [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The file does exist! After some research I came upon this post: [Single-name references are removed by the SDK when targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2 and referencing a package with the same assembly](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net472/KnownIssues/613745%20-%20Single-name%20references%20are%20removed%20by%20the%20SDK%20when%20targeting%204.7.2.md)

I removed the System.Http.Net reference hoping it will use it from the framework, same error. Next, I tried the workaround stated there:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.2.0">
    <ExcludeAssets>All</ExcludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Same error.

Any help or troubling shooting ideas would be welcome

Comment: Have you tried referencing System.Net.Http via Nuget Package? I think latest stable is v4.3.3 and see if it fixes the issue

Comment: Yes I have tried, not the latest version though (4.2.0). Can give it a try with the new version but since everything works locally well I dont really think that should be the problem

Comment: I suggest give it a try.

Comment: I would expect what you are seeing happen when targeting 4.7.1, but if you are targetting 4.7.2 then this issue should never happen. Would you mind sharing an msbuild binlog so that we can try to investigate what is the issue here and find a solution? In order to produce a msbuild binlog, simply build your project from a developer command prompt by running: `msbuild yourProject.csproj /t:rebuild /bl` That should create a msbuild.binlog file on your current directory, so if you could upload that I'm happy to help you out.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood doesn't work with v4.3.3

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot share the complete build log as it contains some user and proxy server details. However, If you need some screenshots from MSBuild Structured Log Viewer I could share that. Anyhow, thank you for your comment.

Comment: Please post it if you manage to figure out. I have the same issue which is only occuring in prpduction for me